# vue-router query parameter as array with keys

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I need to generate a vue-router link that contains an array with string keys as a query parameter.
I want the resulting URL to look like

```
url?param[key]=value
```

I need these kinds of query parameters to match an existing backend infrastructure, so renaming/refactoring them is not an option.

I've tried to use a router-link like the one below, but the `param` object just get's serialized as `%5Bobject%20Object%5D`. Maybe there is an option to change the way this object is serialized within vue-router?

```
<router-link :to="{name: 'xyz', query: {param: 'value'}}">link</router-link>
```

Does anyone have helpful input? Thank you :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After spending some time vue-router GitHub issues and their docs, I figured it out.

When creating your RouteConfig, import `qs` and set the `parseQuery` and `stringifyQuery` methods as follows:

```
parseQuery: (query: any): object => {
    return qs.parse(query);
},
stringifyQuery(query: any): string {
    let result = qs.stringify(query, {encode: false});

    return result ? ('?' + result) : '';
}
```

It is important to include `{encode: false}`, otherwise the square brackets will get URL encoded.

Comment: Not sure what we are importing, with import `qs` ?

Comment: You want { encodeValuesOnly: true }, not encode: false

Answer (score 2):

Addition to Martin's comment,

Exact Router config should be :

```
// https://github.com/ljharb/qs
import qs from 'qs';

const router = new Router({
    routes: [
        // ...
    ],
    // set custom query resolver
    parseQuery(query) {
        return qs.parse(query);
    },
    stringifyQuery(query) {
        var result = qs.stringify(query);

        return result ? ('?' + result) : '';
    }
});
```

and query parameters inside routes will be automatically converted url string and parsed as an object when accessing $router.query .

Comment: the encode false is missing in your example: qs.stringify(query, {encode: false});

Comment: https://github.com/ljharb/qs

Comment: I suspect youd actually want  { encodeValuesOnly: true }, not encode: false